# Error c4996 Checked Iterators

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I use VC++ 2013 and I have a following code:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#define D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <object.pb.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Object object;
    object.set_id(1);
    object.set_name("Ermolaev Ivan");
    object.set_vertex(300.0f);
    fstream output("myfile", ios::out | ios::binary);
    object.SerializeToOstream(&output);
    return 0x0;
}
```

But following error continue displayed.

```
Error   1   error C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 2132    1   ProtobufTest
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `D` prefix is not necessary, it's an indicator for the compiler when you introduce the define on the command line.

You should define this as simply `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. It's best to do this in `Project Properties -> C++ -> Preprocessor`, to have it consistent across all your code.

Comment: to clarify, `-D` is the prefix to define, and `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` is the macro to define

Answer (score 8):

if you using selfmaden iterators then ***typedef iterator _Unchecked_type;*** inside of custom iterator, make microsoft std library trust it is checket.

```
class iterator: public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, const uint8_t>
{
public:

    typedef iterator _Unchecked_type;
// your implementation here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I spent a lot of time to find this information. Only downside is that is obviously coupling my code to the STL implementation of MSVC/Dinkumware.

Comment: I have been looking for this information for months! Thank you.