# Exprtk parser not working on VS 2015?

Tags: c++, parsing, exprtk

I am trying to use the parser from this site:

http://www.partow.net/programming/exprtk/

on VS 2015. Unfortunately, I get the following error while compiling exprtk_simple_example_01 (one of the example files included in the download with the parser):

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4996   'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be       
unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are 
correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See 
documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'  TEST        
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xutility 2229
```

Why is that? Is this parser not compatible with VS 2015?

Comment: `See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'` - have you tried that :) Also... [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655496/error-c4996-checked-iterators)

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THE SOLUTION IS:

> In solution explorer, right click the project, select "properties". The project property page will open. Expand the ">C/C++" entry in the tree on the left and select "Preprocessor" under that. The top entry in the right pane should be "Preprocessor Definitions". In that edit box, add _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS, separating it from the other entries with a `;`
>
> Then set the linker flag /bigobj!